# Webix widget getting instantiated twice when used along with angular gridster

Tags: angularjs, webix

I am trying to create a dashboard layout by using angular-gridster(for layout) and angular webix(for creating widgets). One problem that I am facing in this is, the webix widgets are getting initialised twice when the dashboard page comes up which internally re-renders all the widgets twice. A small sample of the application is available at the below fiddle link

```
    <body>
      <div ng-controller="SampleController">
        <div gridster="gridsterOptions">
          <div class="widget-container" gridster-item="widget" ng-repeat="widget in widgets">
            <div webix-ui="widget" webix-ready='resize(root)'></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>

$(function() {
  webix.protoUI({
    "name": "SampleWidget",
    $init: function(config) {
      alert("In $init");
      this.$view.className = config.css;
      this.$view.innerHTML = "Hai";
    }
  }, webix.MouseEvents, webix.EventSystem, webix.ui.view);

  //Initialising app
  var webixApp = angular.module('webixApp', ['webix', 'gridster']);

  var gridsterOptions = {
    columns: 12,
    margins: [10, 10],
    outerMargin: false,
    mobileBreakPoint: 600,
    width: 'auto',
    colWidth: 'auto',
    minSizeY: 15,
    minSizeX: 2,
    rowHeight: 10
  };

  //controller
  webixApp.controller('SampleController', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.gridsterOptions = gridsterOptions;
    $scope.widgets = [{
      view: 'SampleWidget',
      id: 'Sample',
      css: 'sample-widget'
    }];

  });
  angular.bootstrap($("body"), ["webixApp"]);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rajisht/L3a3k624/

Can anyone give the reason for this or any fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

The protoUI constructor is used to initialize a new instance of your custom component, but to insert your custom component in the app you are required to use **webix.ui** the same way when you insert any library component.
So, if you add webix.ui in you controller as shown below then it will bind properly your protoUI and will instantiate it only once.

```
webixApp.controller('SampleController', function($scope, $timeout) {
$scope.gridsterOptions = gridsterOptions;
$scope.widgets = webix.ui({
  view: 'SampleWidget',
  id: 'Sample',
  css: 'sample-widget'
});
```